# Angular 2 Format Date Time Issue

Tags: html, mysql, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to format a date time value, my json call returns me a value like this:

```
2017-02-01T13:00:00.000Z.
```

And in my html code I have a `p` like this:

```
<p item-right>{{Solicitud.fecha_fin | date:"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"}}</p>
```

And this shows me this result:

```
01/02/2017 07:01
```

And that is wrong.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Please provide plunker example, because i am not getting same result in my code.

Comment: Are you speaking about the `time`? Maybe if you use `HH:mm` it shows you the expected output.

Comment: please include the expected output, and include any relevant information to replicate the problem. (we *assume* that "2017-02-01T13:00:00.000Z." is the value of `Solicitud.fecha_fin`?)

Answer (score 0):

From experience the piping of date does not work on iOS and when building the application there will be errors so I recommend just getting the date string and slicing it in a separate function.